# Checkboxes group and only one required, in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have checkbox group:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="zainteresowany1" ng-model="zainteresowany1">Stażem
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="zainteresowany2" ng-model="zainteresowany2">Pracą
</div>
```

And I would like to validate form if **nothing** checkbox is selected.
If nothing is selected: form is invaild.

How to make?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `ng-model` attribute the same for both checkboxes and set the `value` attribute for what value you want each to have when that checkbox is selected. Then you can validate the form by making sure the variable you use for `ng-model` is not undefined.

Example:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="zainteresowany1" ng-model="zainteresowany" value="foo" /> Stażem
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="zainteresowany2" ng-model="zainteresowany" value="bar" /> Pracą
</div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
if (!$scope.zainteresowany) {
    // Form is invalid
} else {
    // Form is valid
    var value = $scope.zainteresowany;
}
```

Comment: okay, but next I validate if my form is vaild. What should add I to my form to change form to invaild ?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone have other solution ? '

I want to validate form and IF ANY CHECKBOX is selected i want to make form $inval